# Модуль python _mysql кодировка utf8

Tags: python, utf-8, mysql

При попытке заполнить поле БД строкой с русскими символами :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import _mysql

db = _mysql.connect(host="localhost",
                          user="root",
                          passwd="pwd",
                          db="coolinar"
                          )
ingredient = 'мука'

db.query("INSERT INTO ingredients (name) VALUES ('%s')" % ingredient)
```

В БД появляется не "мука" а абракадабра 'Ð¼ÑƒÐºÐ°'. Кодировка БД - utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
db = _mysql.connect(
    host="localhost", 
    user="root", 
    passwd="pwd", 
    db="coolinar", 
    charset = "utf8", 
    use_unicode = True
);
```

Параметр use_unicode можно и опустить.

[MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

[Writing UTF-8 String to MySQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вместо 'мука' надо писать u'мука'